# How to Change the list selected item color in the navidgation drawer?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am starting from the Android Studio example of navigation browser. I'm customizing everything i want, all is ok but i can't find how to change the selected item color in the navigation drawer... For now it's green and i don't manage to change that.

I tried with a selector drawable but no way, i managed to change the whole background but not juste the selected one.

Sorry if it's a noob question but i spent hours yesterday on google and here without finding :/

[image: Green color i want to change]

---

**Finally, i managed to make it work.**
The problem was the "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1".

It's an android built in xml so you can't deal with colors you want.

So i created a file named `nav_drawer_layout.xml` containing the same as the "android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1" file.

Then i tweaked it changing the **android:background** attribute like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:background="@drawable/nav_drawer_colors"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

It refers to the the `nav_drawer_colors.xml` **selector** that you have to create:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/selected_drawer" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/selected_drawer" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/pressed_drawer" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/backgroung_drawer" />
</selector>
```

selected_drawer, pressed_drawer and backgroung_drawer are defined in the values\colors.xml as always.

<strike>Now all is ok, except the shadow effect that works everywhere but not in the listview ^^</strike>
EDIT: just specify a background color in the fragment navigation drawer layout (fragment_navigation_drawer.xml) and remove the
`<item android:drawable="@color/backgroung_drawer" />` in the `nav_drawer_colors.xml` file :)

*Hope that it will help others who have the same problem :)*

Comment: Use list selector for Listview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Through coding you can achieve by this on item click of ListView:

```
int save = -1;
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    parent.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(
                            Color.parseColor("#A9BCF5"));

                    if (save != -1 && save != position) {
                        parent.getChildAt(save).setBackgroundColor(
                                Color.parseColor("#d6e6ff"));
                    }

                    save = position;
          });
```

***Using Selector:***

Make one file named `select.xml` in `drawable` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/green" />
 <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

Now set this file to as a Listselector for ListView in xml file. Like,

```
android:listselector="@drawable/select"
```

or use as a background too

```
android:background="@drawable/select"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply !

When i try programmatically it works, but the first time i open the drawer it's still green. When i change selected and i come back, it's ok, it's the good color.

I didin't find where to initialize the good color.

And with the selector it still don't work, i can change background but it's like the app don't recognize the state selected.

Comment: And you said "Now set this file to as a Listselector for ListView in xml file. Like, android:listselector="@drawable/select" "

I didn't understand where. I tried in my fragment_navigation_drawer.xml but i get errors.

Comment: Ok, i put listselector and not listSelector so i got errors.
I become crazy with this listview... Now it's work when i press, but it ignore the selected state. I think it's because it's not my layout, it's a predefined layout in android:

`mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                new String[]{

                }));`

Answer (score 2):

Create xml file in drawble

**list_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

**list_item_bg_normal.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

  <gradient
      android:startColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
      android:endColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
      android:angle="90" />

</shape>
```

**list_item_bg_pressed.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

 <gradient

      android:startColor="#aed200"

      android:endColor="#aed200"

      android:angle="90" />

</shape>


<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! Unfortunately, it seems that the app doesn't recognize the state activated, focused or selected. It apply the good backgroung but the selected one is still green :/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1.Create list_selector.xml in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/dark_green" android:state_activated="true" />
<item android:drawable="@color/sliver" android:state_focused="true" />
</selector>
```

2.Then set `list_selector.xml` as background in listview custom designed layout.

```
android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! 
Unfortunately, it seems that the app doesn't recognize the state activated, focused or selected. It apply the good backgroung but the selected one is still green :/